# Como agrupar por semanas usando sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query

estou com o seguinte problema . Tenho várias requisições , e estou querendo agrupa-las por semanas . Já vi vários exemplos ,mais quase nenhum me ajudou, gostaria de saber  se existe uma função que quando coloca-lá no Group by o resultado da query sairia assim:Ex

DATA        NºRequisições 
01/01/2016       32
08/01/2016       44

Obrigado até mais.

Comment: Você precisa que a data de contagem da semana comece do primeiro dia de cada mês?

Comment: Não necessariamente, meu problema era: quantas requisições cada executor realizou e depois gerar um gráfico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando a Função `date_trunc` do próprio Postgres :

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('week', dt_registro),
    SUM(vl_total)
FROM
    tb_nota
WHERE
    dt_registro BETWEEN '01/02/2016' AND '01/03/2016'
GROUP BY 
    1
ORDER BY 
    1
```

- `week` seta para semana

Answer (score 3):

No MySQL, utilizando a função [week](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week), pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT YEAR(dia) as ano,
DATE_ADD(dia, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(dia)) DAY) as semana,
SUM(requisicoes) as total_requisicoes
FROM tabela GROUP BY ano, WEEK(dia)
```

veja o exemplo no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee0c0/2/0)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode agrupar pela semana e apresentar a data cheia:

(MySQL)

```
SELECT
    min(data_requisicao) as `Semana Requisição`,
    count(*)             as `Contagem Requisições`
FROM
    tbl_requisicoes
GROUP BY 
    WEEK(data_requisicao)
```